# Usage of mpi4py Sendrecv

Tags: python, communication, mpi4py

Am trying to learn mpi4py.  The following test code looks pretty straightforward to me

```
#shift.py

from mpi4py import MPI

comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()

nxt = (rank+1)%size
prev = (rank-1)%size

num = rank
num2 = 0

print rank, num

num2 = comm.Sendrecv(num,dest=nxt,source=prev)

print rank, num2
```

But running the thing ....

```
mpirun -np 4 python shift.py
```

... raises this error from all procs:

```
TypeError: message: expecting buffer or list/tuple
```

I haven't been able to find any fairly complete documentation on Sendrecv.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is that some message you are passing - num as it looks, is expected to be cast as a Buffer or List data type. Trying doing [num] in the call to Sendrecv or cast num into a buffer. For buffer casting see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html?highlight=buffer#text-i-o)

Comment: @theWanderer4865 Tried that earlier, figured I would try again.  Re-defined num2 = [].  In Sendrecv argument, [num] gave error ValueError: message: expecting 2 to 4 items and list(num) gave error TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.  THanks, though.  Any other ideas are most welcome.

Comment: Yeah, I would go for casting the data as a buffer - see if you can stick a string in there or something to see if it will automatically cast strings as buffers.

Comment: @theWanderer4865 FWIW, I can pass numpy arrays no prob.

Comment: @theWanderer4865 If you're interested, Sendrecv (which I use) and sendrecv (note lower case) are two different routines.  Sendrecv works with buffers.  sendrecv is much more generic and works fine with what I am trying to do.  Would you have thought that?  I never would!   Sheesh!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If anyone's interested,  turns out that Sendrecv (which I use) and sendrecv (note lower case) are two different routines. Sendrecv works with buffers. sendrecv is much more generic and works fine with what I am trying to do.  The only place I could find this discussed is [here](http://wiki.gwdg.de/index.php/Mpi4py).

Comment: Another place it is discussed is in the tutorial: http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/tutorial.html : "Communication of generic Python objects
You have to use all-lowercase methods" and "Communication of buffer-provider objects: You have to use method names starting with an upper-case letter"

Comment: @Rob Latham  Well, I looked at that page, but I just missed it.  Thanks!

Comment: this bit of orthogonality (upper case for buffers, lower case for pythony-things) holds for a lot of mpi4py... but not for file i/o.  for file i/o you must use numpy arrays and the upper-case version -- it's not entirely clear what "write a tuple to disk" would mean, and there's no lower-case version.